# How to locate a text in a table and referring the element click on another element using Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am having trouble working my head out, as what is the best way to search a specific *Text (CustId)* on a web table & once I have found the search text then click on a *Select-Button* present at the end of the row. Now, I do have an ElementId for the table and progressive ElementId on each *Select-Button*
Sample of the source code given below --

```
<table class="w-table w-table-zebra w-table-hover" id="cust-found-table">
        <tbody><tr>
          <th class="w-table-header w-table-width-60">Cust name</th>
          <th class="w-table-header w-table-width-25">Cust Id</th>
          <th class="w-table-header w-table-width-15"></th>
        </tr>
        <!----><tr>
          <td class="w-table-row">Superman</td>
          <td class="w-table-row">12345</td>
          <td class="w-table-row text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-sm w-btn-jetson px-4" type="button" id="cust-found-btn-0">Select</button>
          </td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="w-table-row">Spiderman</td>
          <td class="w-table-row">23456</td>
          <td class="w-table-row text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-sm w-btn-jetson px-4" type="button" id="cust-found-btn-1">Select</button>
          </td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="w-table-row">Batman</td>
          <td class="w-table-row">34567</td>
          <td class="w-table-row text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-sm w-btn-jetson px-4" type="button" id="cust-found-btn-2">Select</button>
          </td>
        </tr><tr>
```

This potentially may be a duplicate post, but couldn't find a similar one. Any help is appreciate.

Go get started I have done as below but couldn't get this working --

```
var theSelector = "button[id*='" + cust-found-btn + "']";    
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cust-found-table"));
        IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        IList<IWebElement> rowTD;
        foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
        {
            rowTD = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

            if (row.Text.Equals("searchtext"))
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("cust-found-btn")).Click();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the respective button with text as **Select** with reference to any of the **Cust Id**, you can write a function which will accept the **Cust Id** as a reference and invoke `click()` on the corresponding element with text as **Select** as follows:

- Function:

  ```
  public void clickSelect(string CustID)
  {
      driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='w-table w-table-zebra w-table-hover' and @id='cust-found-table']//tr//td[@class='w-table-row'][text()='" + CustID + "']//following::td[1]/button[@class='btn btn-sm w-btn-jetson px-4' and starts-with(@id,'cust-found-btn-')]")).Click();
  }
  ```
- Now you can call the function with the desired **Cust Id** from anywhere within your script as follows:

  ```
  clickSelect("12345")
  //or
  clickSelect("23456")
  //or
  clickSelect("34567")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

To :

```
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table#cust-found-table tr td:first-child"));
```

and you can retrieve it using for each loop :

```
foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow){
  if (row.Text.Equals("Superman")){  
   driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[text()='Superman']/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'text-center')]/button")).Click();
}
}
```

**OR:**

A better way would be to have one separate method for this requirement.

```
public void searchAndClick(string name) {
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table#cust-found-table tr td:first-child")); 
foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow){
  if (row.Text.Equals(name)){  
   driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[text()='"+name+"']/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'text-center')]/button")).Click();
}
}  
}
```

and you can call it like this :

```
searchAndClick("Spiderman")
```

Comment: Actually I am indeed having a separate method and is passing parameter and has the ability to search for the text been passed in the test. The issue I am having is getting the XPath right. The xpath I am getting by selecting a specific row is like --  `//*[@id="cust-found-table"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]`

Comment: you can use `searchAndClick` method from my answer which will take string as a name arugument and in xpath `//td[text()='"+name+"']/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'text-center')]/button` would do the clicking. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can try like below

```
 //to get all rows in table
    List<WebElement> rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='cust-found-table']/tbody/tr"));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {

        //check text in first cell of each row
        if(rows.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("td[1]")).getText().equals("requiredCustIdHere")) {
            //click on third cell of required row
            rows.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("td/button")).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can click the correct cust id's select button as below

**Code:**

```
        //expected Customer ID needs to be specified here
        String expectedCustID = "12345";

        IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cust-found-table"));
        IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

        foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
        {
            //Cust Id will be placed in Second Coloum and hence xpath is defined as td[2]
            var custId = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[2]")).Text;

            if (custId.Equals(expectedCustID))
            {
                row.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();
            }

        }
```